# How to evaluate Integro-Differential Equation using Laplace convolution?

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, integro-differential-equations

Can someone please explain how I begin to evaluate the following integro-differential equation?

I know that it involves a convolution, but the $y(τ)$ within the integral is throwing me off.
$$\int_0^tcos(t−τ)y(τ)dτ − \frac {dy(t)}{dt} = −t$$
subject to $y(0) = 4$

If anybody could show me what to do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Laplace convolution theorem says $L[f(t)*g(t)] = F(s)G(s)$. Applying it to the above (which I havent checked that the convolution is indeed the correct form) should give: $\frac{s}{s^2+1}Y(s) - (sY(s) - 4) = -\frac{1}{s}$.

Comment: Is that last term supposed to be $\frac {-1}{s^2}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake